# How to use CSS transitions on react useState elements?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-hooks, css-transitions

I have a website in which I want to change between different HTML sections, and during these changes that happen in a click of an button I want for the section to for example just fade in.

I made a little test run here is the html:

```
   const [isTestWorking, setIsTestWorking] = useState("test-1");
   
   {isTestWorking == "test-1" && (
            <section 
              className={`test1 ${isTestWorking == "test-1" ? "show" : ""}`}
            >
              <h1>Testing 1</h1>
              <button
                onClick={() => {
                  setIsTestWorking("test-2");
                }}
              >
                Transition
              </button>
            </section>
   )}

   {isTestWorking == "test-2" && (
            <section 
              className={`test2 ${isTestWorking == "test-2" ? "show" : ""}`}
            >
              <h1>Testing 2</h1>
              <button
                onClick={() => {
                  setIsTestWorking("test-1");
                }}
              >
                Transition
              </button>
            </section>
   )}
```

And here is the CSS:

```
   .test1 {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.8s ease-in-out;
   }

   .test1.show {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 0.8s ease-in-out;
   }

   .test2 {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.8s ease-in-out;
   }

   .test2.show {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 0.8s ease-in-out;
   }
```

I expected for this to work just fine but I think that the element gets loaded up onto the website after the animation has already played in the background.
I don't know what to do know so if you could please help me I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With copilot I found out that when I use animations instead of the transitions It does finally fade in like I wanted it. Just for reference here is the CSS:

```
.test1, .test2 {
  animation: fade-in 1.5s forwards;
}

@keyframes fade-in {
 from { opacity: 0; }
 to { opacity: 1; }
}
```

And here is the changed html:

```
{isTestWorking === "test-1" && (
  <section className={`test1`}>
      <h1>Testing 1</h1>
  </section>
)}

{isTestWorking === "test-2" && (
  <section className={`test2`}>
      <h1>Testing 2</h1>
  </section>
)}

<button
  onClick={() => {
    setIsTestWorking("test-2");
  }}
>
  Transition
</button>
```